# Count occurrences of key in nested dictionary with same value then delete if occurrence more than x with python

Tags: python

I currently have a dictionary of dictionaries in Python. They may lo0ok something like this:

```
stocks = {
    "VPER": {
        "mentions": 6,
        "score": 120,
        "currentPrice": 0.0393,
    },
    "APPL": {
        "mentions": 16,
        "score": 120,
        "currentPrice": 0.0393,
    },
    "NIO": {
        "mentions": 36,
        "score": 120,
        "currentPrice": 0.0393,
    }
}
```

What I am trying to do is look through the dictionaries and count how many times `mentions equals 5`, then if that count is 10 remove the nested dictionary (APPL, NIO and so on). So if I had `NIO, APPL, TSLA, EPR, EKG, LPD, TTL, AGR, JKR, POP` as nested dictionaries and they each had their `mentions` key set to a value of `5` then I would want to remove them all from the `stocks` dictionary.

I am not really sure how to go about this, any documentation, advice or examples would be highly appreciated.

CLARIFIED LOGIC:
If there are ten occurrences of `mentions: 5` then delete `all` nested dictionaries where the mentions are equal to five.

Comment: Remove entry if their count is equal to 5 10 times? Your logic isn't clear from the description.

Comment: So what I mean is if there are ten occurrences of mentions: 5 then delete all nested dictionaries where the mentions are equal to five.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
counter = sum(value["mentions"] == 5 for key, value in stocks.items())
if counter > 10:
    stocks = {key: value for key, value in stocks.items() if value["mentions"] != 5}
```

Comment: Perfect thank you, I didn't realise it was this simple. One more question, if I wanted to just check if there are 10 occurrences of any mentions with the same value, is that possible?

Comment: that would be possible but that would complicate the answer because then you would have to count every present item in the key `mentions`. I would suggest you ask a new question for the same.

Comment: Do you have a link to a rough example of how I might extend your answer to incorporate this?

Comment: that would probably use `collections.Counter` or `collections.defaultdict`.

Comment: I have been trying different things for about 40 minutes but I don't think I am getting anywhere. Would you be able to roughly extend your answer with a small example of what you have just mentioned?

Comment: you should ask a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228446/discussion-between-vishal-singh-and-alphadmon).

Answer (score 1):

You would get the sum of mentions equal to 5 with:

```
sum(1 for k,v in stocks.items() if v["mentions"]==5)
```

And you would delete the nested dicts upon that condition with:

```
stocks={k:v for k,v in stocks.items() if v["mentions"]!=5}
```